# Can an iMac connect to a Windows 7 or 8 PC via Network in the Finder

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, imac, workgroup

I can see my Windows 8 computer when I click on Network in Finder.
When I select the Win 8 system it asks for a password. When I enter the same password that I have set up to login to Windows it rejects it.
I can login as Guest and see the Public folder on Windows. So I know that the iMac can display the Windows file system. But that is very limited. I can't freely access my computer.
I need to login as a user with password and access the entire system.

Comment: Have you enabled any shared files on your Windows PC?  If not, the only thing that would be shared is the public folder by default.  When you add the shared files/folders (right click > sharing > advanced sharing), you also need to specify user permissions - so make sure you put your username in the allowed and select the appropriate read/write perms.

Comment: Yes to all of the above.

Comment: I can edit the advanced sharing properties on Windows and change the settings of Everyone to Read and Write. After doing this, when I connect as Guest from Mac OSX (Mavericks) I can freely access all files and edit and delete them. This is my desired goal, but I'd prefer to not have it left open to everyone and instead connect as a Registered User with password. But for some reason when I use my user name on Windows (the one I login with) and the password I use to login to Windows (my Microsoft account) it is rejected.

Comment: Did you try specifying your domain?  I.e. username: `mypcname\myusername`?

Comment: That did not work. I used the same name for username and myusername. Did you mean for those to be different ? Also my user name has a space in it "William Smith". I tried both with the space and with %20 for the space.